# Google Analytics - how to set custom variable with DataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I dont know much about Google Analytics (GA). 
My job now is to find the way to send data from a webshop to be shown in GA at custom variables (key 1) and it must sending with dataLayer.

The data to send is for telling that the visitor is new or have been a customer.

After researching I found only the way to send with ga.js

_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "ReturningVisitor", 'Yes', 1]);

But its not work for me, because we send the other data to GA with DataLayer.

This is the example code we send other data:

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

```
var dataToPush = {
  'event': 'transactionEvent',
  'transactionId': '112256',
  'transactionAffiliation': 'CompanyName',
  'transactionTotal': 250.00;?>,
  'transactionTax': 0,
  'transactionShipping': 0,
  'transactionProducts': []
}

dataLayer.push(dataToPush);
```

So how to add the custom variable (key 1) to this dataLayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the custom variable to dataLayer however you like. E.g.:

```
var dataToPush = {
  'event': 'transactionEvent',
  ...
  'anyNameForYourCustomVariable': 'ReturningVisitor'
}

dataLayer.push(dataToPush);
```

Important step is to set it up in GTM. You have follow this steps:

1. Create a new DataLayer variable in GTM and set 'Data Layer Variable Name' to 'anyNameForYourCustomVariable'
2. in GTM go to GA Tag you want to send and edit its Google Analytics Settings
3. click on 'More Settings' -> 'Custom Dimensions' and then click on 'ADD CUSTOM DIMENSION'
4. Set index to '1' and for 'Dimension Value' select the Data Layer Variable you have created

For more information you can visit developer guide: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try this after I get the access to GTM.